# Allow touches to pass through a UICollectionView to it's Superview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

Let's say I have a ViewController with a `UICollectionView` sitting on it.  How can I get Touches to pass through the `UICollectionView` and into the ViewController's `TouchesBegan`/`TouchesMoved`/`TouchesEnded` functions?  I've done this many times with `UIScrollViews` simply by setting **`ExclusiveTouch = false`** and the touch would then be allowed to pass through the `UIScrollView` to it's superview.  But that same approach doesn't work with `UICollectionViews`.  Any ideas?

Set's up `UICollectionView`:

```
partial class CyanViewController : BaseViewControllerWithCollection
{

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Constructors
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public CyanViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Setup collection view
        this.SetupCollectionView();
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("TouchesBegan");
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Private Methods
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    private void SetupCollectionView ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("SetupCollectionView");
        try
        {
            // Instantiate collection view
            this.CollectionView = new UICollectionView(
                this.View.Bounds,
                new UICollectionViewFlowLayout() { 
                    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
                    ItemSize = new CGSize(75, 115),
                    SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(20, 20, 20, 20)
                }
            );

            // Setup delegate and data source
            this.CollectionView.Delegate = new ProductTypeCollectionViewDelegate(this);
            this.CollectionView.DataSource = new ProductTypeCollectionViewDataSource(this);
            this.CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(BaseCollectionViewCell), BaseCollectionViewCell.s_millaCellId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception : " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        // Add collection view to view
        this.View.AddSubview(this.CollectionView);
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Class: SeedsCollectionViewDataSource
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public class ProductTypeCollectionViewDataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource
    {

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Properties
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        private CyanViewController _parentController;

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Constructors
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public ProductTypeCollectionViewDataSource (
            CyanViewController a_parentController
        )
        {
            this._parentController = a_parentController;
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        private ProductTypeCollectionViewDataSource ()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // UICollectionViewDataSource Implementation
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (BaseCollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (BaseCollectionViewCell.s_millaCellId, indexPath);

            cell.Label.Text = "Woot";

            return cell;
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return 10;
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Class: SeedsCollectionViewDelegate
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public class ProductTypeCollectionViewDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegate
    {

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Properties
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        private CyanViewController _parentController;

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Constructors
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public ProductTypeCollectionViewDelegate (
            CyanViewController a_parentController
        )
        {
            this._parentController = a_parentController;
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        private ProductTypeCollectionViewDelegate ()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // UICollectionViewDelegate Implementation
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public async override void ItemSelected (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("ItemSelected indexPath.Row = " + indexPath.Row);
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

}
```

Sets up `UIViewController` that holds the `CollectionView`.  I want to get touches in `TouchesBegan`/`Moved`/`Ended` here!

```
partial class BaseViewControllerWithCollection : UIViewController
{

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Properties
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public UICollectionView CollectionView { get; set; }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Constructors
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public BaseViewControllerWithCollection (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.View.ExclusiveTouch = false;
        this.View.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("TouchesBegan");
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("TOuchesMoved");
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("TouchesSended");
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

}
```

This is my `UICollectionView` Class.  I couldn't get touches in the `UIViewController` so I tried getting them here, but couldn't....

```
public class MyCollectionView : UICollectionView
{
    public MyCollectionView ( CGRect frame, UICollectionViewLayout layout ) : base (frame, layout)
    {
        this.ExclusiveTouch = false;
        this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        this.BackgroundView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        this.BackgroundView.ExclusiveTouch = false;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("MyCollectionVIew TouchesBegan");
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("MyCollectionVIew TouchesMoved");
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded (touches, evt);

        Console.WriteLine ("MyCollectionVIew TouchesEnded");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the touch to be recognized by both the collection view and the underlying view, or only the underlying view?

Comment: I want the collectionview to function, but when you simply tap, or press-hold-drag to have the underlying view to capture the TouchesBegan/Moved/Ended.  So probably both.  UIScrollViews can do both, so I'm trying to figure out why UICollectionViews can't.  Or if they can how can they?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the correct way, but overriding touchesBegan, etc. in the collection view subclass, and calling it on super as well as on the nextResponder seems to work. In Objective-C, I did this,

```
@implementation RDCollectionView

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Then, in the underlying view, I also implemented these three methods, and handled the touches.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I've done that before successfully with things other that Collections in Xamarin.  But for some reason my Touches functions aren't even getting called with the either the UICollectionView or the ViewController.  This is very odd.  It's almost like the CollectionView is capturing the touches and not letting them go anywhere else.   Hence my experimenting with the ExclusingTouch = false

Comment: @LampShade: May be your collectionview cell is getting those events

Comment: This solution is clean. I am doing for native app and yours idea is useful.